# How to get iOS application version?

Tags: iphone, version, coronasdk

For my iOS application I need to access the application version number. In Objective-C and Xcode done by accessing Info.plist but I want this functionality in the Corona SDK.

Is this possible? If yes then how?

Comment: Would you not simply make a variable with the application version number and remember to update it yourself?  If it is possible then it would be available via [system.getPreference](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/system-os).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build-time properties can be provided in an optional build.settings file, which uses Lua syntax.  You can set and retrieve plist values via the sample shown [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/configuring-projects).

```
settings =
{
   orientation =
   {
       default = "portrait",
       supported =
       {
            "portrait", "portraitUpsideDown", "landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft"
     }
},


iphone =
{
    plist =
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation = "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight",

        UISupportedInterfaceOrientations =
        {
            "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
            "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"
        },

        UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = true,
        UIStatusBarHidden = true,
        UIPrerenderedIcon = true

       }
    }
}


settings.iphone.plist["UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad"] = "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait"
settings.iphone.plist["UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad"] = 
{
    "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
    "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown"
}
```